# javascript/ajax – ajax requests very slow - time out issue?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I programmed an experiment in javascript/jquery extensively using ajax to communicate with the server / execute php scripts on the server.

Now, a friend of mine wants to use the scripts in japan and is running into problems that I haven't encountered before.

For example he has to press submit buttons several times instead of just getting redirected to the next page or he sees placeholder symbols instead of the data that is stored in the mysql database and should have been fetched (and replace the placeholders).

In the last case, the script is quite straightforward. A $.post request is executed in the document ready function, which then executes a function in which the javascript replacements take place.

Now we are kind of lost what could be the cause of it. It seems to work fine on my side.
The server is located in europe and he also had some issues with proxy servers.

Could that be a problem?
Could it be that the $.post commands are just very slow or even time out?

Is there anything that can be done about this to make the scripts run reliably on his side?

I am happy to provide more specific information if needed, however currently I am a little bit lost and don't know what to look for specifically.

Thanks for any help!

---

edit:
Here is the jquery code for one specific example where we encountered this problem:

```
function updateContent() {
  $.post("php/earnings.php", 
  { 
    type: "contribution", 
    grp : group, 
    pbnr : PbNr, 
    multiplier : multiplier 
  }, processAndShow);

  function processAndShow(data) {
    // here are just jquery commands updating html elements
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateContent();
});
```

the earnings.php file contain roughly 150 lines of code with 15 mysql_query requests.

I also had a look at the connection diagnostics in firefox for the earnings.php $.post request:

```
Connection: "Keep-Alive";
Keep-Alive: "timeout=1, max=96"
```

has it possibly something to do with the timeout / max settings of the apache server?

Comment: Can you show us the code?, that will help us to help you

Comment: No code, no help. You should be doing debugging yourself with a DOM inspector and a net inspector (e.g. firebug's net tab, httpfox, etc..) to see what's going on.

Comment: First of all open `network` tab in your dev toolbar and research where is the problem: DNS, sending, waiting or receiving part of request?

Comment: Check the response you get back from the service. This will tell you if the service has timed out. Ajax doesnt set a timeout value by default but your service might impose one